# How to find end state probabilities of a state transition probability matrix?

Tags: markov-chains

Given I have a state transition matrix where we move from state to state by the roll of a die, with 13 in-game states plus states 14, 15 are the two end game states (14 one outcome, 15 another), how do I compute the total probability that say 14 will happen?
If I sum the column 14 and 15 shouldn't it come to 1?
There are also the following properties: we do not move backward and we can only visit a state one time.

[image of matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsGJv.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.